# phone-cat app, npm start not working

Tags: node.js, npm

Im following the tutorial from AngularJS site, the phone-cat app. 
I cannot get npm start to work, has anybody had the same issue on windows? 
Im running the commands through Git shell.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. For those who have the same issue, instead of running "npm start" I run "http-server" and the port used is 8080, and not 8000, like the tutorial suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it. For those who have the same issue, instead of running "npm start" I run "http-server" and the port used is 8080, and not 8000, like the tutorial suggest.